# Can I allow the extension user to choose matching domains?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can I allow the domain matching for my extension to be user configurable?
I'd like to let my users choose when the extension runs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To implement customizable "match patterns" for content scripts, the Content script need to be executed in by the background page using the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript) method  (after detecting a page load using the [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onUpdated) event listener).

Because the match pattern check is not exposed in any API, you have to create the method yourself. It is implemented in [`url_pattern.cc`](https://code.google.com/p/chrome-browser/source/browse/trunk/src/chrome/common/extensions/url_pattern.cc), and the specification is available at [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html).

Here's an example of a parser:

```js
/**
  * @param String input  A match pattern
  * @returns  null if input is invalid
  * @returns  String to be passed to the RegExp constructor */
function parse_match_pattern(input) {
    if (typeof input !== 'string') return null;
    var match_pattern = '(?:^'
      , regEscape = function(s) {return s.replace(/[[^$.|?*+(){}\\]/g, '\\$&');}
      , result = /^(\*|https?|file|ftp|chrome-extension):\/\//.exec(input);

    // Parse scheme
    if (!result) return null;
    input = input.substr(result[0].length);
    match_pattern += result[1] === '*' ? 'https?://' : result[1] + '://';

    // Parse host if scheme is not `file`
    if (result[1] !== 'file') {
        if (!(result = /^(?:\*|(\*\.)?([^\/*]+))(?=\/)/.exec(input))) return null;
        input = input.substr(result[0].length);
        if (result[0] === '*') {    // host is '*'
            match_pattern += '[^/]+';
        } else {
            if (result[1]) {         // Subdomain wildcard exists
                match_pattern += '(?:[^/]+\\.)?';
            }
            // Append host (escape special regex characters)
            match_pattern += regEscape(result[2]);
        }
    }
    // Add remainder (path)
    match_pattern += input.split('*').map(regEscape).join('.*');
    match_pattern += '$)';
    return match_pattern;
}
```

### Example: Run content script on pages which match the pattern

In the example below, the array is hard-coded. In practice, you would store the match patterns in an array using [`localStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info) or [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html).

```js
// Example: Parse a list of match patterns:
var patterns = ['*://*/*', '*exampleofinvalid*', 'file://*'];

// Parse list and filter(exclude) invalid match patterns
var parsed = patterns.map(parse_match_pattern)
                     .filter(function(pattern){return pattern !== null});
// Create pattern for validation:
var pattern = new RegExp(parsed.join('|'));

// Example of filtering:
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        var url = tab.url.split('#')[0]; // Exclude URL fragments
        if (pattern.test(url)) {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
                file: 'contentscript.js'
                // or: code: '<JavaScript code here>'
                // Other valid options: allFrames, runAt
            });
        }
    }
});
```

To get this to work, you need to request the following [permissions in the manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html):

- **`"tabs"`** - To enable the necessary `tabs` API.
- **`"<all_urls>"`** - To be able to use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` to execute a content script in a specific page.

### A fixed list of permissions

If the set of match patterns is fixed (ie. the user cannot define new ones, only toggle patterns), `"<all_urls>"` can be replaced with this set of permissions. You may even use [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html) to reduce the initial number of requested permissions (clearly explained in the [documentation of `chrome.permissions`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html)).

Comment: @Rob W ; There is a `match` array in parse_match_pattern function but it looks undefined. I tried to get what that means exactly but I couldn't find. What is 'match' array exactly?

Comment: @YasinOkumus Thanks for bringing it up. It's a mistake, and I should have called it `result`.

Comment: +1 great answer. I was wondering if there was any way to apply Chrome matching for a user-defined list in a content script?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28930209/comparing-user-specific-url-list-with-current-url

Comment: @user2381114 Put the `parse_match_pattern` function in a content script, and then you can use it in a content script as you wish. This function does not depend on the background page (or any other extension API), so if you wish, you can even use it in a web page.

Comment: @RobW Great, thanks. Would that function take much modification to make it so that if no leading protocol is entered (e.g. `www.example.com`), it matches all like `*//www.example.com`. And also if `example.*/about` it would match `example.com/about` and `example.co.uk/about`.

Comment: @user2381114 The method shown in this answer is a strict implementation of Chrome's [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). If you want anything else, you should create your own parser and evaluator (or look on the internet for existing ones).