# chrome.tabs.executeScript and injection only into pages that pass matches filter in manifest.json

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm attempting to perform programmatic injection of my *content script* into open tabs after my Chrome extension is reloaded or updated.

My script may call the following method for an arbitrary tab:

```
var manifest = chrome.app.getDetails();
var scripts = manifest.content_scripts[0].js;
chrome.tabs.executeScript(nTabID, {
    file: scripts[0]
    });
```

This works, except when I try to load it into a page that was not supposed to have a *content script* running according to the `matches` clause in the `manifest.json`. I get the following exception:

> Cannot access contents of url "actual-url-here". Extension manifest
>   must request permission to access this host.

So my question. Is there a way to parse the page URL and see if it matches `matches` clause from `manifest.json` and prevent calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` for unnecessary URL?

PS. I understand that one "hacky" solution is to catch-and-ignore exceptions. So I'm not asking for it.

Comment: Take a look at `chrome.runtime.getManifest()`

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I did and then what?

Comment: You defined your matches in your manifest, did you not? From there it's a simple matter of searching it to match the URL.

Comment: Well, I'm obviously not on your level and that is why I'm asking this question.... can you show me how to search it from the matches in the manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) for a list of tabs, use the `url` attribute to filter by a [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns). [As of Chrome 39](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128924), this key also supports an array of match patterns. If you need to support Chrome 38 or earlier, or if you got the tabs without `chrome.tabs.query`, use the [`parse_match_pattern` function from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433271/can-i-allow-the-extension-user-to-choose-matching-domains/12436854#12436854) to filter tabs. To use it, copy that function and include it within your (background) page (e.g. by pasting it before the following snippet).

```
var content_scripts = chrome.runtime.getManifest().content_scripts;
// Exclude CSS files - CSS is automatically inserted.
content_scripts = content_scripts.filter(function(content_script) {
    return content_script.js && content_script.js.length > 0;
});
content_scripts.forEach(function(content_script) {
    try {
        // NOTE: an array of patterns is only supported in Chrome 39+
        chrome.tabs.query({
            url: content_script.matches
        }, injectScripts);
    } catch (e) {
        // NOTE: This requires the "tabs" permission!
        chrome.tabs.query({
        }, function(tabs) {
            var parsed = content_script.matches.map(parse_match_pattern);
            var pattern = new RegExp(parsed.join('|'));
            tabs = tabs.filter(function(tab) {
                return pattern.test(tab.url);
            });
            injectScripts(tabs);
        });
    }

    function injectScripts(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            content_script.js.forEach(function(js) {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                    file: js
                });
            });
        });
    }
});
```

The previous snippet inserts a content script in all tabs. It is **your responsibility** to make sure that inserting the script does not conflict with an earlier/later instance of your script.

Mimicking the [`all_frames`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#all_frames) and [`match_about_blank`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#match_about_blank) functionality is slightly more complex, because the [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) API cannot be used to target specific frames ([crbug.com/63979](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=63979)). If you want to inject in frames as well, then you have to insert in every tab (because there might be a frame under the non-matching top-level frame that matches the URL) and check the page's URL **within** the content script.

Finally, note that your content script must also deal with the fact that it may run at a point different from ["run_at"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at). In particular, content scripts that rely on `"run_at":"document_start"` might fail to work because calling `chrome.tabs.executeScript` will cause a script to be injected far past the `document_start` phase.

Comment: Thanks. Just to note, your `crbug.com/63979` link is broken.

Comment: I'm currently on Chrome v.37, so can't try it yet. Just from curiosity though, is there a stat showing how many Chrome users are on what version?

Comment: @c00000fd In general you can assume that most users are on the latest version, because of automatic updates. See http://www.chromium.org/developers/calendar for the release calender; Add about 6-8 weeks to the listed dates to see the approximate date of when everyone is at that version.