# syntaxis on matching urls from an array saved on extension storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been going through the Google chrome APIs in order to work on an extension and the processes regarding it.  I stumbled upon the chrome.webRequest https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest I have been tinkering with the syntax but I am lost with it because I'm relatively new to programming and using the chrome APIs

What I was thinking was using chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function callback) and then making it use chrome.tabs.remove to remove the tab is it matches the array but I am not sure how to do that

I have this for the removing of the tab using the google chrome match filters

```
var urlArray= ["*://facebook.com/*", "*://example.com/*", "*://google.com/*" ];
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    for (var i = 0, len = urlArray.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (tab.url.indexOf(urlArray[i]) > -1) {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
            alert("things");
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You need to understand what `indexOf` does.

Comment: This may help, if not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433271/can-i-allow-the-extension-user-to-choose-matching-domains

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that, if you check for `"*somestring*"`, the `.indexOf()` function will actually look for that exact string, meaning that asterisks aren't used as a wildcard, and will only match if the string contains them.

Here's an example:

```
"hello".indexOf("*hello")     // -1 there's no *
"123hello".indexOf("*hello")  // -1 there's no *
"*hello".indexOf("*hello")    // 0  here it is, in the first position
"123*hello".indexOf("*hello") // 3  and again, in the fourth position
```

So, in your case, you should use [Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp), like this:

```
var urlExp= /https?\:\/\/(facebook|google|example)\.com/i;

chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function (tab) {
    if (urlExp.test(tab.url)) {
        chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
        alert("things");
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a question however, so lets say that i want to close one more website how could I add it, since you use
     var urlExp= /https?\:\/\/(facebook|google|example)\.com/i;
which from my understanding only closes the ones that were established before hand

Comment: @user4556006 you can add it in the parenthesis, like this: /https?\:\/\/(facebook|google|example|newSite)\.com/i