# Comparing user-specific URL list with current URL?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, url, google-chrome-extension

I have a whitelist  where users can enter specific URLs/URL patterns (only targetting `http` and `https`.

I would like to transfrom and compare these URL/URL patterns so that the **wildcard selector** (`*`) can be used like so

> **user enters:** `example.*/test`
>
> **I want to transform this to:** `*//*.example.*/test`
>
> **so that it matches:** `http://www.example.com/test`, `https://example.co.uk/test`

Another example:

> **user enters:** `http://www.*.com/*`
>
> **I want to transform this to:** `http://www.*.com/*`
>
> **so that it matches:** `http://www.blah.com/test`, `http://www.other.com/null.html`

and

> **user enters:** `www.example.com/*`
>
> **I want to transform this to:** `*//www.example.com/*`
>
> **so that it matches:** `http://www.example.com/testtwo`, `https://www.example.com/arfg`

The reason I want to insert a leading protocol (if it wasn't included by the user) is because I am using this to compare against the current tab URL.

I get this array of URL strings and would like to compare them with the current url, but am having trouble matching all use cases:

```
 "isNotWhitelisted" : function(){
      var whitelist = MyObject.userLists.whitelist;
      var currentUrl = document.location.href;
      for(var i=0; i<whitelist.length; i++){
          var regexListItem = new RegExp(whitelist[i].toString().replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".+"));
          if(currentUrl.match(regexListItem)) {
              return false;
          }
      }
      return true;
  },
```

1. Firstly, the regex conversion matches end cases (e.g. `example.com/*` but not kinds like `example.*/about`
2. This is part of a Chrome extension, is there not a better/easier way to do this maybe using inbuilt methods?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: if you aren't sure if it's correct shouldn't you create an array of test url's and set a flag for each if it should pass or not?

Comment: This may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12433271/can-i-allow-the-extension-user-to-choose-matching-domains A JS-based implementation of Chrome's match patterns.

Comment: Your regexp conversion is wrong; leaving `.` instead of literal `\.` is not going to work properly. And that's just one problem.

Comment: @Xan So `\.+` would be a better replacement? It was working for `example.com/about` and not matching `example.com/`, but yeah it doesn't match `example.*/about`. Probably very inefficient too as new regexp object each loop

Comment: I don't want to go into much detail; `.+` matches (1+ any character), but the period that's left in `example.com` is also matching any character; `example_com/test` will match.

Comment: @Xan Ahh I completely get it now, so `.replace(".", "\\.").replace("*", ".+")` would be an improvement but still lots more issues. Cheers for the advice

Answer (score 1):

```
whitelist.forEach(function(listItem){
     var rgx = new RegExp(listItem.replace(/\./g,'\\.').replace(/\*/g,'.*'));
     if(rgx.test(url)) {
       // current URL matches URL/URL pattern in whitelist array! 
     }  
  })
```

If you dont replace, the pattern 'www.*.com' match also to 'wwwocom'.

If you want use another special characters you can use this:

```
var rgx = new RegExp(listItem.replace(/(\.|\[|\]|\{|\}|\(|\)|\+|\?|\\|\$|\^)/g,'\\$1').replace(/\*/g,'.*'));
```

Comment: `.replace(/\*/g,'.*'))` should be `.replace(/\*/g,'.+'))`, since he doesn't want `*` to resolve to null.

Comment: I don't know what he want, but `*` in wildcards it's `.*` in regex.

Comment: I think he was pretty descriptive when he said: `I want * to be a wildcard selector, so www.example.com/* would match anything not-null `.  He's defining the `*` wildcard as anything not-null

Comment: What he didn't talk about was greedy matching, or if parameters include match constraints `http://www.example.com?url=anothersite.com` or `http://nonmatchingsite.com?url=http://www.example.com`

Comment: He give patterns without protocol , so they cannot be greedy matching.

Comment: @Elad Thanks for the answer, only problem is the `.+` part - this is useful when targetting all subdirectories e.g. `www.example.com/*`, but if the user enters `www.example.*/about` then I would want to match `www.example.com/about`, `www.example.co.uk/about`. Is there any way to tweak it to work with this? Thanks again

Comment: @vol7ron Hi, thanks for the pointers - no constraint matching necessary, only issue with `.+` so far is that I need this wildcard applied to both paths and the full domain names e.g. `example.*/about` matches `example.com/about` and `example.co.uk/about`, also `www.example.com/*/example` and `http://www.*.com` to work as expected kinda thing.

Comment: @user2381114, Elad was on the right path, if I have time I'll help you out. You need non-greedy matching. Also this might be better to split into a two step process, first checking the domain, then checking the path, more for readability.

Comment: @vol7ron Probably a good idea, thanks. I've updated with a couple of examples if that makes it a bit clearer

Comment: You want this pattern `*://*.*.*/*`?

Comment: @Elad That looks right. If `http/https` and `www` is not specified by user, then just target all (I am only targeting `http/https` protocols, and `www` sometimes not necessary e.g. `https://stackoverflow.com` has no `www`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a greedy matching, I think you need request the user enter the pattern in this format: `*://*/*`

You can check this in this way:

```
var special_char_rgx = /(\.|\[|\]|\{|\}|\(|\)|\+|\?|\\|\/|\$|\^|\|)/g; // I think that all...
var asterisk_rgx = /\*/g;
var pattern_rgx = /^([^:\/]+):\/\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)$/g;

function addPatern(pattern, whitelist) {
    var str_pattern = pattern.replace(asterisk_rgx,'\\*');
    var isMatch = pattern_rgx.test(str_pattern);
    if (isMatch) {
        pattern = pattern.replace(special_char_rgx,'\\$1').replace(asterisk_rgx, '.+');
        whitelist.push(new RegExp('^'+pattern + '$'));
    }

    pattern_rgx.lastIndex = 0; // Otherwise RegExp.test save this value and destroy the tests!

    return isMatch;
}
```

If you want handle the protocol/ domain/ path in different ways you can do it that way:

```
    if (isMatch) {
        var protocol = RegExp.$1;
        var domain= RegExp.$2;
        var path_query = RegExp.$3;            
        // Your logic...
    }
```

Comment: I've updated the question with a couple of examples. Thanks for the answers +1

Answer (score -1):

Hm, m.b. create RegExp from whitelist items? If it works as you expected:

```js
new RegExp('example.com/*').test('http://example.com/aaaa')
```

Just create regexp from each item in whitelist

```js
whitelist.forEach(function(item) {
  new RegExp(item).match(URL);
});
```

Comment: new RegExp('www.*.com').test('http://www.wwwocom.org') // true! You need replace special characters

Comment: This is **horrendously wrong**. The syntax of regular expressions makes some of those patterns to compile as valid, but the meaning is wrong in all cases.